# Arcs are not responding to key functions?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm reading a tutorial book on how to program python. In it there's this game called the 'pie game'. The game is where these 4 numbers pop up on the screen, you press the corresponding number to have the arcs pop up. Once all the numbers are pressed, all the arcs pop up to from a circle and the circle turns green. I entered the code as it said from the book. I ran and the four numbers popped up, but when i pressed the corresponding number nothing happens.
heres the code:

```
import math
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("The Pie Game")
pygame.display.set_caption("The Pie Game - Press 1,2,3,4")
myfont = pygame.font.Font(None, 60)

color = 200, 80, 60
width = 4
x = 300
y = 250
radius = 200
poisition = x-radius, y-radius, radius*2, radius*2

piece1 = False
piece2 = False
piece3 = False
piece4 = False

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_1:
                piece1 = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_2:
                piece2 = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_3:
                piece3 = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_4:
                piece4 = True
    #clear the screen
    screen.fill((0,0,200))

    #draw the four numbers
    textImg1 = myfont.render("1", True, color)
    screen.blit(textImg1, (x+radius/2-20, y-radius/2))
    textImg2 = myfont.render("2", True, color)
    screen.blit(textImg2, (x-radius/2, y-radius/2))
    textImg3 = myfont.render("2", True, color)
    screen.blit(textImg3, (x-radius/2, y+radius/2-20))
    textImg4 = myfont.render("4", True, color)
    screen.blit(textImg4, (x+radius/2-20, y+radius/2-20))

    #should the pieces be drawn?
    if piece1:
        start_angle = math.radians(0)
        end_angle = math.radians(90)
        pygame.draw.arc(screen, color, position, start_angle, end_angle, width)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, color, (x,y), (x,y-radius), width)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, color, (x,y), (x+radius,y), width)
    if piece2:
        start_angle = math.radians(90)
        end_angle = math.radians(180)
        pygame.draw.arc(screen, color, position, start_angle, end_angle, width)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, color, (x,y), (x,y-radius), width)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, color, (x,y), (x+radius,y), width)
    if piece3:
        start_angle = math.radians(180)
        end_angle = math.radians(270)
        pygame.draw.arc(screen, color, position, start_angle, end_angle, width)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, color, (x,y), (x,y-radius), width)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, color, (x,y), (x+radius,y), width)
    if piece4:
        start_angle = math.radians(270)
        end_angle = math.radians(360)
        pygame.draw.arc(screen, color, position, start_angle, end_angle, width)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, color, (x,y), (x,y-radius), width)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, color, (x,y), (x+radius,y), width)

    #is the pie finished
    if piece1 and piece2 and piece3 and piece4:
        color = 0,255,0

    pygame.display.update()
```

This is what I'm having trouble with:

```
    if piece1:
        start_angle = math.radians(0)
        end_angle = math.radians(90)
        pygame.draw.arc(screen, color, position, start_angle, end_angle, width)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, color, (x,y), (x,y-radius), width)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, color, (x,y), (x+radius,y), width)
```

But generally all of the "if piece1,2,3,4 parts because i copied them and altered a little to save time. I tried going on the books website to find answers but it did'nt have the answers. I want to know how to make the arcs pop up when i press the corresponding number.
Any help will do!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the traceback, when something is wrong. After running your code I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 54, in <module>
    pygame.draw.arc(screen, color, position, start_angle, end_angle, width)
NameError: name 'position' is not defined
```

After looking for the definition of position, I have noticed that you have made a typo.

```
poisition = x-radius, y-radius, radius*2, radius*2
```

Fixing this to position, fixed the issue.

There is one more thing, you forgot to import the `sys` module. You use it in for `sys.exit()`.